# Error mv target is not a directory and missing argument to `-exec'

Tags: find, rm, mv

I am creating a script in Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.5 (Maipo) to  find all files named `test*.txt` that are 10 days older than 6 months. The original directory that I'm copying from contains a valid file, however when I try to move the files it errors out. The script and the error message is listed below. Why does it fail and what I can do to fix it?

```
find /INTER/f/d/o/ -type f -name "test*.txt" -mtime +190 -exec mv /INTER/f/d/o/"test*.txt" /INTER_ARCHIVE/f/d/o/ {} \;

mv: target    /INTER/f/d/o/test1.txt    is not a directory
mv: target    /INTER/f/d/o/test2.txt    is not a directory
mv: target    /INTER/f/d/o/test3.txt    is not a directory
mv: target    /INTER/f/d/o/test4.txt    is not a directory
```

Also, after the files have sat in the archive directory for 7 months plus 10 days delete them. Using the script below, I get the following error.

```
find /INTER_ARCHIVE/f/d/o/ -type f -name "test*.txt" -mtime +400 -exec rm {};

find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

Comment: As a general debugging hint, put `echo` in front of the `mv` so you can see the command being run.

Answer (score 1):

Your first command:

```
find /INTER/f/d/o/ -type f -name "test*.txt" -mtime +190 -exec mv /INTER/f/d/o/"test*.txt" /INTER_ARCHIVE/f/d/o/ {} \;
```

Here, I assume that you'd want to move the found files that match the pattern and are sufficiently old.  The `mv` command bit is malformed and should look like

```
-exec mv {} /some/destination/path \;
```

That is, "move the found file (`{}`) to some destination".

It is unclear from looking at the command where you want the files to be moved, but as you wrote it, you are moving files *to* the found pathnames.  This fails since the `mv` tries to move multiple files to something that is not a directory.

In you second command,

```
find /INTER_ARCHIVE/f/d/o/ -type f -name "test*.txt" -mtime +400 -exec rm {};
```

you have simply failed to terminate the argument to `-exec` correctly.  The last bit should look like

```
-exec rm {} \;
```

or simply

```
-delete
```

if your implementation of `find` supports that.

See also "[Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)".

Answer (score 0):

Your first command:

```
find ... -exec mv /INTER/f/d/o/"test*.txt" /INTER_ARCHIVE/f/d/o/ {} \;
```

will pass to `mv` the arguments `/INTER/f/d/o/test*.txt` (literally, with the asterisk), `/INTER_ARCHIVE/f/d/o/` and then the current file that `find` is processing. `mv` sees three arguments, so it expects to move the first two to the third, which then must be directory.

The `test*.txt` will not expand to any matching filenames, since `find` doesn't run the `-exec` command through a shell (you have to use `-exec sh '...' \;` for that). Not that you'd want to, anyway, since globbing `test*.txt` here would defeat the point of the `-mtime`.

What you probably want is

```
find ... -exec mv {} /INTER_ARCHIVE/f/d/o/ \;
```

to move the file `find` is currently processing to `/INTER_ARCHIVE/f/d/o/`.

Or with GNU `mv`:

```
find ... -exec mv -t /INTER_ARCHIVE/f/d/o/ {} +
```

to process multiple files with one call to `mv`.